# How should I handle promises and callbacks with waterline and bluebird?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, sails.js, waterline, bluebird

I'm having MULTIPLE problems while using sails because I can't understand waterline promises and its logic.

I tried both built in **bluebird promises** and also even a `async.waterfall` implementation and couldn't succeed.

In a few words, I'm writing code for an API which performs db queries and by triying to use callbacks, it's Never responding.

This is what I tried on pure promises:

```
changeFormation: function (request,response) {

  console.log("changeFormation");
  var lineupId = request.params.id;
  var newFormation = request.param('formation');
  var newLineUp = request.param('lineup');
  console.log("Receiving" + newFormation);

  if ( ["5-4-1", "5-3-2", "4-5-1", "4-4-2", "4-3-3", "3-5-2", "3-4-3"].indexOf(newFormation) === -1 ) {
    console.log("No válida");
    return response.send(409, "La táctica elegida no es válida");
  }

  LineUp.findOne({id: lineupId}).
  then(function (foundLineUp) {

    console.log(foundLineUp);
    if (!foundLineUp)
      return response.send(404);

    if (! foundLineUp.formation) {

      foundLineUp.formation = newFormation;

    LineUp.update({id: foundLineUp.id}, foundLineUp).exec(function (err, saved) {

      if (err)
        return response.send(500, JSON.stringify(err));

      return response.send(202, JSON.stringify(saved));
    });

    }

    // If a formation was previously set
    else if (Array.isArray(newLineUp) &&  newLineUp.length > 0) {

      newLineUp.formation = newFormation;

      LineUp.update({id: newLineUp.id}, newLineUp).exec(function (err,saved) {
        if (err)
          return response.send(500,JSON.stringify(err));
        return response.stringify(202, JSON.stringify(saved));
      });
    }
    console.log("Never reached");
  }).
  catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    response.send(500,JSON.stringify(err));
  });
},
```

In this above I can see in console **`"Never reached"`**. Why!?

And this is what I tried using async module:

```
addPlayer: function (request,response) {

  // console.log("Add player");
  var lineupId = request.params.id;

  var receivedPlayer = request.param('player');
  var playerId = receivedPlayer.id;
  var bench = receivedPlayer.bench;
  var place = receivedPlayer.place;
  var e, r;

  async.waterfall([

    function (cb) {

      LineUp.findOne().where({id: lineupId}).exec(function (err, foundLineUp) {
        cb(err,foundLineUp);
      });},

    function (lineup,cb) {

      Player.findOne().where({id: playerId}).exec(function (err,foundPlayer) {
        cb(err,lineup, foundPlayer);
      });},

    function (lineup, player, cb) {
      if (!player) {
        console.log("Jugador no existe");
        cb(null, {status: 409, msg: "El jugador " + playerId + " no existe"});
      }

      if (!lineup.formation) {
        console.log("No hay táctica")
        cb(null, {status: 409, msg: "No se ha elegido una táctica para esta alineación"});
      }

      if (lineup.squadIsComplete()) {
        console.log("Ya hay 15");
        cb(null, {status: 409, msg: "La plantilla ya contiene el máximo de 15 jugadores"});
      }

      if (lineup.playerWasAdded(player.id)) {
        console.log("Jugador ya en alineación")
        cb(null, {status: 409, msg: "El jugador ya ha sido agregado a la alineación"});
      }

      if (lineup.fieldIsComplete() && !bench) {
        console.log("Ya hay 11 en el campo");
        cb(null, {status: 409, msg: "Ya se han agregado los 11 jugadores de campo"});
      }

      player.bench = bench;
      player.place = place;

      lineup.players.push(player);

      console.log("MaxForeign " + lineup.reachesMaxForeignPlayers());
      console.log("BudgetLimit " + lineup.reachesBudgetLimit());
      console.log("SameTeam " + lineup.reachesMaxSameTeamLimit());
      console.log("reachesMaxSameFavoriteTeamLimit " + lineup.reachesMaxSameFavoriteTeamLimit());


      // If any of rule restrictions evaluates to true ...
      // Using lodash _.some with out second argument which defaults to _.identity
/*      if ( _.some([ lineup.reachesMaxForeignPlayers(),
                    lineup.reachesBudgetLimit(),
                    lineup.reachesMaxSameTeamLimit(),
                    lineup.reachesMaxSameFavoriteTeamLimit()]) ) {

        return response.send(409, "La inclusión de este jugador no satisface las reglas del juego");
      }*/

      LineUp.update({id: playerId}, lineup).exec(function (err, saved) {
        cb(err, {status: 202, msg: JSON.stringify(saved)});
      });
    }
  ],

  function (err, result) {
    console.log("About to respond");
    if (err)
      respond.send(500);
    else
      response.send(result.status, result.msg);
  });

  console.log("Never reached");
},
```

This gives not a timeout but it's strangely not updating the document when it should. It's logging **`"never reached"`**  and then **`"about to respond"`** but that's normal I guess.

So far, how should I handle it all?

Comment: Why would you expect `console.log("Never reached");` to never be reached? The only case for it not being reached would be if that 404 is sent.

Comment: Uh, those two snippets of code seem to be totally unrelated and use different approaches. Please ask only about a single problem per question (though you might include multiple different approaches to solve it)

Answer (score 2):

> In this above I can see in console "Never reached". Why!?

Because you're mixing async code with sync'd code. If you do:

```
function(){
  console.log('init');
  someAsyncMethod(function callback(){
    return console.log('async done');
  });
  console.log('Never reached');
}
```

You'll get:

```
init
Never reached
async done
```

Because the async code will be executed afterwards. I suggest you read [this](http://www.theprojectspot.com/tutorial-post/nodejs-for-beginners-callbacks/4) and [this](http://book.mixu.net/node/ch7.html) to better understand async callbacks.

> This gives not a timeout but it's strangely not updating the document when it should.

It's hard to say what's going on because we don't know the model definition of `LineUp` and we don't know the contents of `lineup` before and after the `update` call. Are you sure that `LineUp.update()` ran? Why not adding a `console.log()` in its callback to see the result?

> So far, how should I handle it all?

It seems to me you're close to achieving your goal. If you share the `LineUp`'s model definition and some more logging we'll be able to help you more.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response, it's true that I made stupid assumptions in my code and even this post. However I've found the issue, which lead me to total confusion. I've posted a separated question and if you've got experience with Sails I hope you can check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958122